# bash: printf to email Fails, Redirect Succeeds

Tags: linux, bash, postfix

When I pipe the output from printf to mail, the email does not get sent.  When I write the output to a file and redirect input from the file, it works.

e.g. I have a bash script with the following:

```
printf "\nsending email.\n" | /usr/bin/mail -s "email test 1" id@domain-name.com

printf "\nsending email\n" > /tmp/email-test
/usr/bin/mail -s "email test 2" id@domain-name.com < /tmp/email-test
```

email test 2 is delivered but email test 1 is not.

The symptoms are intermittent.  Sometimes both emails go out.  Sometimes the one with the pipe fails.

Whether one or both go out, I get log lines which look a lot like this for both of them:

```
Nov 17 07:39:10 boxtop3 postfix/smtp[12749]: 9A7032C23C5: to=<myname@mydomain.org>, orig_to=<myname@mydomain.com>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[64.233.177.109]:587, delay=1.7, delays=0.04/0/1.1/0.58, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1573994350 z127sm6991417ywb.38 - gsmtp)
Nov 17 07:39:10 myserver postfix/qmgr[12702]: 9A7032C23C5: removed
```

My email is hosted by GMail for both mydomain.com and mydomain.org.  It looks like GMail is intermittently discarding some of my email. Why?

Using:

- GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release
- postfix 3.3.0-1ubuntu0.2
- mail (GNU Mailutils) 3.4

Comment: And what version of of `mail` are you using? Does the message at least get _queued_ in Postfix?

Comment: "postqueue -p" reports "Mail queue is empty".  $? is 0 after each command line with /usr/bin/mail in it

Comment: Please check the Postfix log files.

Comment: Other than a whole bunch of "warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 47: overriding earlier entry: myhostname=private-name.com" I don't see any errors. I'm going to try and find 1-to-1 correspondence between attempts to send mail and "removed" messages in the log file but... it looks like it is an intermittent problem and it isn't happening right now (but it did happen 30 minutes ago!)  I'll try again soon.

Comment: Added info from the log.  It looks like GMail is intermittently discarding some of my messages.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is nothing wrong with either email command.  Each one is reliably sending the message every time it is executed, as shown in /var/log/mail.

My email gets sent to id@domain-name.ORG, which is hosted by GMail.  id@domain-name.org has a rule to forward everything to id@domain-name.COM.

The missing messages ARE found in the mailbox for id@domain-name.ORG.  They are not getting delivered to id@domain-name.COM.  For some unknown reason, GMail is either failing to forward or failing to deliver some of my messages.  There are additional emails which it is failing to forward/deliver -- these messages are simply the first I noticed.